# Weather Command catches error when I type the location

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, openweathermap

I am trying to do weather command for my Discord bot. Everything is okay. But when i run the code and type the location, it catches error.I am using Open Weather Map, and my API KEY is correct, when i type url manually, i get the informations like this

```json
{"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":9.87,"feels_like":7.79,"temp_min":8.19,"temp_max":11.25,"pressure":1027,"humidity":55},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.12,"deg":100},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1680603013,"sys":{"type":2,"id":268730,"country":"GB","sunrise":1680586188,"sunset":1680633422},"timezone":3600,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

But when I try to do with /weather London it catches error

My code is

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { WEATHER_API_KEY } = require('dotenv')
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('weather')
        .setDescription('View the weather for your chosen area')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('location').setDescription('The chosen area\'s weather to show')),
    async execute(interaction, MessageEmbed) {
        const target = interaction.options.getString('location')
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${target}&units=metric&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`).then(response => {
                    const apiData = response;
                    const currentTemp = Math.ceil(apiData.data.main.temp)
                    const wind = apiData.data.wind.speed;
                    const icon = apiData.data.weather[0].icon
                    const cityName = interaction.options.data[0].value
                    const country = apiData.data.sys.country
                    const cloudness = apiData.data.weather[0].description;
                    const { pressure, humidity, temp_max, temp_min  } = response.data.main;

                    const weatherEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(`The temperature is ${currentTemp}\u00B0C in ${cityName}, ${country}`)
                        .addFields(
                            { name: `Maximum Temperature:`, value: `${temp_max}\u00B0C`, inline: true },
                            { name: `Minimum Temperature:`, value: `${temp_min}\u00B0C`, inline: true },
                            { name: `Humidity:`, value: `${humidity} %`, inline: true },
                            { name: `Wind Speed:`, value: `${wind} m/s`, inline: true },
                            { name: `Pressure:`, value: `${pressure} hpa`, inline: true },
                            { name: `Cloudiness:`, value: `${cloudness}`, inline: true },
                        )
                        .setThumbnail(`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`)
                        .setColor("#FFC0CB")
                interaction.reply({ embeds: [weatherEmbed] })
            }).catch(err => {
                interaction.reply(`Please enter a valid city name`)
             })
    },
};
```

My discord bot types `Please enter a valid city name`, but I type London, Tokyo, they are valid.

I firstly expected that, the problem is in the API key. But I checked it, and It was true

Comment: Have you logged `err` to see what it says?

Comment: I logged, it said that,       message: 'Invalid API key. Please see https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.'

Comment: There's your problem, double check your tokens